# how make AVFoundtion stretch and rotate to be LandScape on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a camera input from AVFoundtion, how can I stretch and rotate it to length UIView
LiveStreamView class I took the code from the documents to associate it with uiview
I would love to understand how to do it, thanks.
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5B8A.jpg)

my code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
class AVFoundtionHandler {
    
    let captureSesstion = AVCaptureSession()
    
    
    
    init() {
        
        configure()
        
    }
    
    func configure() {
        
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                  for: .video, position: .back)
        
        guard let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!),
            captureSesstion.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else { return }
        captureSesstion.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        
    }
    
   
    
}
```

- 

```
class LiveStreamView:UIView {
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    
    /// Convenience wrapper to get layer as its statically known type.
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }
    
   
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with

- Get device orientation `UIDevice.current.orientation`
- Set the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation` property

```
let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
let videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: deviceOrientation.rawValue)
videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientation ?? .portrait
```

Note that this should run on main thread, or it will crash.

I also prefer to set at the same place the `videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill` (the default is `resizeAspect`)

The main complication is that although `UIDeviceOrientation` and `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` have *some* very similar values, they are not the same and `UIDeviceOrientation` has more values (`faceUp`, `faceDown`, `unknown`). I just gave it `portrait` as the default in such cases, but you need to make whatever is appropriate for your app.

After that you need to watch for device orientation change (with `override func viewWillTransition` of the UIView), and update the same value again if the device was rotated.

This solves the view problem. If you are processing the video, or capturing the image from the camera, it's the whole other set of things you need to do - separate problem though.